# how can I detect floor movements such as push-ups and sit-ups with Kinect?

Tags: tracking, kinect, depth

I have tried to implement this using skeleton tracking provided by Kinect. But it doesn't work when I am lying down on a floor.

According to Blitz Games CTO Andrew Oliver, there are specific ways to implement with depth stream or tracking silhouette of a user instead of using skeleton frames from Kinect API. You may find a good example in video game Your Shape Fitness. Here is [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1GfXhQjxmI) showing floor movements such as push-ups!

Do you guys have any idea how to implement this or detect movements and compare them with other movements using depth stream?

Comment: What SDK are you using (OpenNI, Kinect for Windows)?  What are the angles and relations (e.g., straight on, side view, top-down) that you have tried when tracking the skeleton?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to include the SDK. I am using Kinect and trying to match the pose on the floor from side view. I mean, I am lying down one the floor in sideways orientation.

Comment: By "Kinect" as an SDK, you mean "Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK"?  Is the Kinect hardware looking down on you, or is it positioned at (roughly) the same height when doing a pushup?  I'm asking all these to get a better idea of how the depth frames and skeleton tracking could be used.

Comment: The SDK is Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK. The Kinect hardware is not hanging over me. It's positioned at a desk. Thanks for caring about my problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

What if a 360 degree sensor was developed, one that recognises movements not only directly in front, to the left, or right of it, but also optimizes for movement above(?)/below it? The image that I just imagined was the spherical, 360 degree motion sensors often used in secure buildings and such.

Comment: Thank you KatieK for your comment. Instead of 360 degree sensors, the video Your Shape Fitness has already implemented floor moves recognition with only one kinect. The user is sideways towards Kinect and this pose usually can break the skeleton tracking provided by kinect, however, it still can filter the user from back ground. That game did pretty well. I guess maybe they are using techniques related to graphic recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Without another sensor I think you'll need to track the depth data yourself. [Here](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=145347)'s a paper with some details about how MS implements skeletal tracking in the Kinect SDK, that might get you started. They implement object matching while parsing the depth data to capture joints in the body, you may need to implement some object templates and algorithms to do the matching yourself. Unless you can reuse some of the skeletal tracking libraries to parse out objects from the depth data for you.

Comment: Thanks for the paper. I'm trying to understand it